# Error while adding Tab bar controller between two view controllers? Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8, uistoryboardsegue

Exception occurs: **-[UITabBarController setUserAccount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setUserAccount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.**
[image]
 1. I have totally **4** view controllers in my xcode project.
    **First** view controller is **LoginViewController** and **Second** View controller is **DialPad ViewController** and **third** is
    **Contact ViewController** and **fourth** is **callHistory viewController**.

1. Now, I want to **merge** last three viewControllers as one view by
   adding Tab bar controller. I have successfully added tab bar
   controller, but it gives above exception.   I clearly found that
   where is the exception occurs, but don't know how to clear it.
2. In **LoginViewController**, When user logins with using username and
   password, its first checks username and password correct. If both
   are correct means it enters into next view controller, else it stays
   in same Login ViewController.

For this function, I have used

```
-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{

    if([self checkLogin])
    {
       return YES;
    }
    else
    {
       return NO;
    }
}
```

Now when return YES means, it goes to Tab Bar Controller, and it gives exception.

Please give any other solution to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are you calling setUserAccount ? Or is it the property of any view controller?

Comment: thank you @Arjuna . I was using the property, which controls another view controller. when I removed that property, now my dialler is  working perfectly.